# CURL requests don't start Xdebug in VSCode

Tags: php, curl, visual-studio-code, xdebug

When debugging in VSCode using Xdebug extension, if you come across a line that makes a curl request with `curl_exec()`, and you have a breakpoint at the endpoint of that curl, the Xdebug doesn't stop on that breakpoint.

I remember with PhpStorm you can set Max. Simultaneous connections to 3-4 connections and it was working. However, I have no idea how to set it in VS Code's `launch.json` settings.

My php.ini config:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey="XDEBUG_VSCODE"
```

My `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "XDEBUG_VSCODE",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/",
        "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
        "xdebugSettings": {
            "max_data": -1
        }

    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you pass "debug me" xdebug cookie/request parameter in your cURL request? If not -- xdebug may simply be unaware that you are trying to debug this *separate* request (as it's sent independently from your original debug session). If that's so -- `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` may help (or try placing `xdebug_break()` in your code). In any case: I suggest to enable xdebug logging to see if it even tries to make that 2nd debug session. P.S. No ideas on possibility of simultaneous debug sessions in VSCode.

Comment: @LazyOne No. I don't pass `xdebug` cookie to the `curl`, as the curl request is done in the lines of a PHP file. So by setting a breakpoint in the endpoint file of that curl request, it wasn't giving the break I wanted. Maybe the xdebug and PHPStorm combination somehow was passing the session to the curl. I definitely wasn't doing it manually. I will try the `xdebug_break()` and then check for the xdebug logging you mentioned, as I don't want to use `xdebug.remote_autostart=1`, because this will force the debugger to stop in all the files, at least that's what I believe it does.

Comment: *"Maybe the xdebug and PHPStorm combination somehow was passing the session to the curl"* Nope. It's a separate request -- you are in charge of what needs to be happening. *"because this will force the debugger to stop in all the files, at least that's what I believe it does."* Not exactly -- not every file .. but only entry points (so will not be triggered inside include/required/class autoloading) -- only the first script that PHP executes during particular request (and sub-request is a separate request).

Comment: I tried passing the cookie, have the `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` and use `xdebug_break()`. Nothing did work. As you said a sub-request is a separate request I think VS Code cannot handle that.

I was reading through these github issues

[Launch/Debug multiple configurations at once](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1616),
 [Support multi target debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13426),
 [multi debug: productise 'composite' launch config](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14842)

VS Code seems cannot handle multiple connection/requests-subrequests